# Clickhouse Exception Code 1002 host port failed to respond

Tags: java, spring, jdbc, clickhouse

This error happens 1-2 times a week. Everything is working fine but suddenly some queries cant be executed because clickhouse throws this exception.

> [https-jsse-nio-28443-exec-10] ERROR SellinaChatService:100 ->
>   Exception : ClickHouse exception, code: 1002, host: 164.52.197.xxx,
>   port: 8123; 164.52.197.xxx:8123 failed to respond

This is my keep alive timeout

```
<keep_alive_timeout>3</keep_alive_timeout>
```

What can be the possible cause of this issue?

Comment: Please provide a [mre] and the full exception stacktrace. You tagged your question with MySQL? Why did you do that when your question is about ClickHouse?

Comment: It's a bug in CH JDBC driver. JDBC driver does not expect that TCP connection is closed and need to recreate it (it expects that it's still open because of keep_alive).